# By using sed change IP Address what ever it is in brackets and quotes as in Suricata.yaml

Tags: sed, ubuntu-14.04, suricata

I need to change IP address using sed in suricata.yaml file infront of HOME_NET.

```
HOME_NET: "[172.20.16.25]"
```

I can manage what ever IP address by using the following regex.

```
sed -i "s/[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}/"$IP"/g"
```

Problem is it will change all IP addresses in file. I just interested in that is in front of  HOME_NET.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -i "/^ *HOME_NET/s/[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}/"$IP"/g"`

To elaborate a bit: a single line of sed script is composed of a line matching rule (called *address* in the documentation) and an action to be executed (*command*). The `/^ *HOME_NET/` part is a simple line matching rule, while the `s/../../g` part is the substitution command. If you don't specify a line matching rule, all lines are matched.

Try `man sed` to learn a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working fine if HOME_NET is at start of a line  but what if there ate unknown number of spaces before HOME_NET as in suricata.yaml file.

Comment: I edited the regex. You have to add ` *` ('<space><star>') after the line starting anchor `^` to account for leading spaces.